# Access Management(Authorization) in Web Project with IPD, Gateway and Micro Services

Tags: web, authorization, microservices, api-gateway, idp

I have a Web project which is composed of a frontend, an IDP mostly used for authentication, an API Gateway to communicate with services and multiple backend services for different purposes.

Now that I need a good way of handling access management with the role and permission definitions, I started looking at different solutions and I'm looking for suggestions. Here are the options that I could think of so far;

1. Using IDP's (it's Keycloak in my case) solution: In this case, I will be restricted to it's capabilities and interfaces, which I don't like that much since I might need a more complex solution.
2. Implementing my own solution: This is what I'm close to due to the reason I mentioned above. In this scenario, I'm think of following options;

- Handle all at Gateway level
- Handle at each micro service separately
- Handle at each micro service by consuming another middleware responsible for authorization

I know each option has its own advantages and disadvantages, but I'd like to get some opinions about what could be the best to handle authorization in such architecture.